# How can I substitute multiple occurrences of junk strings in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, filtering

In the image, 'muddle' is the string containing junk words and the strings I want to extract. There is a fixed list of junk words - the good strings could be literally anything.

[image]

You can see this formula has correctly extracted "moo" and "coo", which are not in the list of junk words. The formula is below.

```
    =LET(junkStart,FILTER(SEARCH(Table1[junkwords],Table2[muddle]),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table1[junkwords],Table2[muddle]))),

junkEnd,FILTER(SEARCH(Table1[junkwords],Table2[muddle])+LEN(Table1[junkwords])-1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table1[junkwords],Table2[muddle])+LEN(Table1[junkwords])-1)),

goodstart,FILTER(junkEnd+1,(junkEnd+1<=LEN(Table2[muddle]))*(ISERROR(XMATCH(junkEnd+1,junkStart)))),

goodend,FILTER(junkStart-1,(junkStart-1>=LEN(1))*(ISERROR(XMATCH(junkStart-1,junkEnd))))+1,

goodchars,goodend-goodstart,

TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,MID(Table2[muddle],goodstart,goodchars)))
```

This works well, but it falls down if a junk word occurs more than once. See below.

[image]
The only difference is that 'woo' occurs twice in the second example.

I need a single cell solution. VBA is not an option for me. Using the name manager would be untidy, as would nested formulas.

I've got this far with formulas, which as far as I can tell is the furthest anyone has got with the 'removing multiple words from a cell' problem. I can see the issue - once SEARCH locates the start of a string in a cell, it doesn't go looking for a second occurrence of that string. But I don't know how to find the start of every instance of every string. Can anyone help?

Comment: Couldn't you use substitute() to replace words from muddle using junk words and fill down formula so you get ;moo;;coo in the end? Start with `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,";")` in C2 then `=SUBSTITUTE(C2,B3,";")` in C3 and fill down for each junk word...  assumping muddle is in A and junkwords is in B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REDUCE is perfect for this:

`=REDUCE(Table2[muddle],Table1[junkwords],LAMBDA(m,j,SUBSTITUTE(m,j,"")))`

REDUCE starts at the `Table2[muddle]` value as `m` then it substitutes the first value of `Table1[junkwords]` `j` with `""` the outcome becomes the new `m` which will get a substitute of the second value of `j`. The result will be the new `m`, etc.

[image]

If you would want to have it comma separated it becomes more complicated, but you can realize by:

```
=LET(t,SUBSTITUTE(","&REDUCE(Table2[muddle],Table1[junkwords],LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,",")))&",",",,",","),
MID(t,2,LEN(t)-3))
```

This does almost the same as the previous solution, but instead of substituting for blanks it substitutes for `,` and substitutes all duplicate `,,` for singles, so if more substitutes followed eachother it results in one comma. Also, if the first and/or last part got substituted by a single `,`, then the result would have a leading and/or trailing `,`. This is  solved by first adding `,` in the front and back before substituting the double comma's for singles. the result `t` is then wrapped in MID, where the first and last character (both being a `,`) are removed.

[image]

Alternate solution:

```
=LET(t,REDUCE(Table2[muddle],Table1[junkwords],LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y," "))),
SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(t)," ",","))
```

Or in one go if you don't want to use LET:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(REDUCE(Table2[muddle],Table1[junkwords],LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y," "))))," ",",")
```

This replaces the junk words with a space. Regardless how many junk words in between words or how many trailing or leading spaces TRIM will fix it to the words separated by one space only. Substituting the spaces for comma gets to your result.

Comment: This worked, thanks. And you may be the first person on the internet to document how to do it - afaict it was impossible before O365. The only wrinkle is if junk words are repeated several times, you could get 4 or 5 commas which can't all be caught by the sub function. Instead I changed it (using semicolons as the delimeter) to the more readable =TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE(Table2[muddle],Table1[junkwords],LAMBDA(m,j,SUBSTITUTE(m,j,";"))),,";",TRUE))

Comment: I added an alternate solution using TRIM that you might like

Answer (score -1):

There's no single-formula solution if the junkwords list is not fixed.

Instead, you may choose to use the `Substitute()` function on each cell of the "Extracted Strings" column to substitute all occurances of each junk word in muddle, i.e. substitute "boo" muddle, then substitute "voo" in the resulted string, replace "noo" in the resulted string...so on. You will get the last cell.

One point to note though, you need to ensure no substring / partial strings problem in the junkwords or you need to define the rules of processing in order for the solution to be "complete".  Consider the followings:

junk words = abc, def, cde
muddle = 1234abcdef5678

if you process the string in the above order, you got "12345678"
if you process the junk words in reverse order, you got "123abf5678"

Comment: The junkwords are fixed. There's a list of them in the q